# Ruby, initialize method with *

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ruby and found this code:

```
def initialize(*)
  # ...
end
```

What does `*` mean in `initialize` arguments list?

Comment: have you tried researching it? what did you find out

Comment: Though i found about initialize(\*arg) which means it will accept as many argument as we passed to it but i didn't found about initialize(\*). @SRack  explain to me below.

Comment: To be fair to @bisho, I've been hunting for a really good article outlining this approach's use, and it's pretty difficult to come across explanations using _just_ the splat arg and nothing else.

Comment: It's actually a very good question. I don't understand why people are downvoting it - at least include a ref to good documentation about this feature (is there any?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It mean's it's indiscriminate about arguments passed to it, i.e. you can pass as many or as few as you like.

They're 'throwaway' arguments, in that you can't access them subsequently. If you want to access them subsequently, you can use the commonly seen pattern `def initialize(*args)` and access the data via `args`.

It's often called with `super` to accept the arguments from a parent class, perhaps if they're not required.

For example, with your usage:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(*)
  end
end
```

The following will work just fine:

```
MyClass.new(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'etc')
MyClass.new
```

It's largely undocumented, though is covered in the Ruby specs:

```
it "accepts an unnamed '*' argument" do
  def foo(*); end;

  foo.should == nil
  foo(1, 2).should == nil
  foo(1, 2, 3, 4, :a, :b, 'c', 'd').should == nil
end
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation and yes there is super also but i removed it.

Comment: You're welcome - I'm trying to come up with a good example of practical usage, and will update with this shortly. However, if you feel this answers the question, feel free to give a tick @bisho :)